# Can't delete row in GridView, why?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

Good morning,
please, I have dependent GridView and I want delete row, but it not working.
Problem: method 'SmazOrdinacniDobu' (for deleting) have type of parameter OrdinacniDoba, but this parameter is empty... Why? :(
(But update working fine...)

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsOrdinacniHodiny" runat="server" 
    DataObjectTypeName="Praktik.DB.OrdinacniDoby.OrdinacniDoba" 
    DeleteMethod="SmazOrdinacniDobu" InsertMethod="VytvorNovou" 
    SelectMethod="VratVseOrdinaci" 
    TypeName="Praktik.DB.OrdinacniDoby.OrdinacniDoby" 
    UpdateMethod="UpravOrdinacniDobu">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gwOrdinace" DefaultValue="0" Name="id" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="gwOrdinacniDoba" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" 
    onrowupdating="gwOrdinacniDoba_RowUpdating" 
    DataSourceID="odsOrdinacniHodiny" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
    EnableViewState="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" 
        CancelImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ZdravotnickaZarizeni/design/cancel.png" 
        EditImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ZdravotnickaZarizeni/design/pencil.png" 
        ShowEditButton="True" 
        UpdateImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ZdravotnickaZarizeni/design/check.png" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="IDOrdinacniDoby" HeaderText="ID Ordinační doby" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="IDOrdinace" HeaderText="ID Ordinace" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PlatnostOd" HeaderText="Platnost od data" DataFormatString="{0:D}" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PlatnostDo" HeaderText="Platnost do data" DataFormatString="{0:D}" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Den" HeaderText="Den v týdnu" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RezervaceOd" HeaderText="Rezervace od" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RezervaceDo" HeaderText="Rezervace do" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OpakovatPoTydnech" HeaderText="Opakovat po týdnech" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Pritomen" HeaderText="Přítomen?" />
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" 
        DeleteImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ZdravotnickaZarizeni/design/non.png" 
        ShowDeleteButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand the question, can you translate OrdinacniDoba please?

Comment: 'OrdinacniDoba' => Opening hours. I wanna set Opening hours to surgeries (I mean room).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the primary key of your datasource in the gridview with attribute DatakeyNames. In row command or row deleting event, find that key and delete the row.

Comment: ok, I set DataKeyNames to PrimaryKey and it's look working... BUT: Parameter of 'SmazOrdinacniDobu' (DeleteOpeningHour) is class 'OterviraciDoba' (OpeningHour) and it's still empty, only PrimaryKey is set (I use it like parameter for store procedure in DB). How can (where) I get(set) all properties for class 'OrdinacniDoba' (OpeningHour)? In RowDeleting event? (find row by PK, remove parameter and add param.?)

Comment: Instead of passing entire class, OterviraciDoba, why can't you are setting RowValue. If possible paste some CS code. That would be gr8.

Comment: I think, this was is best for life cycle of application. Some code: [ASPX Page](http://pastebin.com/uqxm6BE8) and [CodeBehind](http://pastebin.com/Rt8Q3xWx) and business loginc [manager](http://pastebin.com/wynbuQN9) (DeleteOpeningHour) and [detail](http://pastebin.com/f41bhPpv)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have not provided `DataKeyNames` to your gridview. Secondly you have not provided `Delete method parameter`

```
 <DeleteParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="ParameterName" Type="Int32" />
 </DeleteParameters>
```

Comment: Parameter of 'SmazOrdinacniDobu' (RemoveOpeningHour) is class of 'OterviraciDoba' (OpeningHour).So, I have to rewrite it to int parameter?